# How to check if array contains array in elegant way?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, duplicates

Here is my code in python, which checks whether smaller sub-arrays in big array are inside in one of the sub-arrays. I don't know which is the biggest sub-array's index, so I can not compare against index. Maybe it's good to sort. But if there are more than one big subarrays?
i.e. I want to have in final array only those big sub-arrays, which contain smaller sub-arrays

`[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12],  [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]`

Second, what should I do if order of the elements can be random, e.g.:
`[[1, 3, 2], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12],  [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]`

Here is my code:

```
arr1 = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12],  [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]

arr2 = []
arrInd = 0
arrInd2 = len(arr1)
for k in arr1:
    for n in reversed(arr1):
        if set(n).issubset(set(k)):
            arr2.append(k)

print(arr2)
```

I would like to see as output:

`[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]`

But I have:

`[[4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]]`

UPDATE

Because there were so many good questions I have to add some more details.

1) There is an array of arrays:
`arr1 = [[]]`
2) it contains some sub-arrays like these ones `[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [111, 222, 333], [444, 555], [777, 888], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888], [1000, 2000, 3000]`
What is possible?
1) Inside arrays order may vary: `[4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5]` and `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, so it won't be numerical order, in fact in real data (I am currently testing) there may be even letters, like `A77`, `B81`;
2) There are big and small arrays, there is always a biggest one (or several), which never intersects with other biggest arrays, so here `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` and `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]` - they can not intersect with each other, but they contain some mini sub-arrays;
3) Each big sub-array contains some smaller ones. However, not all of them and some small arrays can exist independently. For instance: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` contains `[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5]`, but it doesn't contain `[7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15]` or `[111, 222, 333]`;
4) There also may be intermediate "big arrays": `[111, 222, 333, 444, 555]` is smaller, compared to `[111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888]` so the first one `[111, 222, 333, 444, 555]` must be excluded.
5*)I would like to add big arrays to `arr2` (final array) without small once, except for case *** `[1000, 2000, 3000]` to `arr2` (final array)

What my code was supposed to do?
It was supposed to go through arr1 and oppose different elements to each other in order to detect whether n element contains k element and vice-versa, as it goes from start to end `for k in arr1:` and from end to start `for n in reversed(arr1):`

UPDATE 2. Comparison of lengths!

`if len(n) < len(k):`

```
    for k in arr1:
        for n in reversed(arr1):
            if len(n) < len(k):
                if set(n).issubset(set(k)):
                    arr2.append(k)
```

And it is much closer. Actually it is almost it, but it makes duplicates, judging by the amount of which, it seems that problem of order (1) is not a problem at all:

`arr2 = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888]]`

It is, of course possible to start the removal of duplicates and to run arr2 in such a way again to get rid of `[111, 222, 333, 444, 555]` which is actually part of `[111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888]`, but there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: It is not clear what exactly do you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to have in arr2 only those big arrays, which contain smaller ones

Comment: I don't see `cycles` defined anywhere.

Comment: What is this for? What are you trying to solve in the first place?

Comment: @KSFT sorry, some of code is from my previous attempts to solve the problem, edited

Comment: @ReutSharabani, can't really understand your question. I am trying to get rid of small sub-arrays if they are part of big sub-arrays, because I need to check the whole thing not the parts. Or do you ask about different order of items in sub-arrays and comparison of sub-arrays?

Comment: Arrays have length, so you can avoid checking if a large array is in a smaller one by checking their sizes first. The number of elements in array `x` is `len(x)`. Same thing goes for `set`s.

Comment: @martineau I don't want to loose any data, if [131, 222, 345] is not a part of anything I still need it, even if it is a short one.

Comment: Guess I don't understand what you're trying to do -- what's the logic behind your desired output? Why are you reversing the array and checking if those elements are a subset of themselves (`set`s have no order)?

Comment: @Anna-Lischen does the sub arrays have any intersection together!

Comment: `If [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] contains [1, 2, 3]`
   `arr2 add [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
`else if [111, 222, 333] is not neither in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] && [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]`
 `arr2 add [111, 222, 333]`
But this (after else if) was a second part, so first of all I though about this thing: `If [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] contains [1, 2, 3]`
   `arr2 add [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`
But I doubt that I can rely on lengths only. What if there is [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]; [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12] and [13, 14, 15, 16]. Let us say [13-16] contains some mini sub-arrays as well [13, 14], [15, 16].

Comment: It seems like [13-16] will be thrown away, because it is shorter than [1-6] and [7-12].
There can also be arrays like [100-150] and [50-57] - length difference is huge, but both are important if they contain some mini-subs like [53, 54, 55] and [101, 108, 149] inside.

Comment: What if you have `[3, 4]` and `[2, 3]` ?

Comment: @Kasra, they may have. But not a full one. Something like that: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] and [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Comment: You're only giving a simplistic example in your question, which doesn't show the logic you're trying to acheive. Try and add more detail and examples of input **and** output, especially the edge-cases.

Comment: @Anna-Lischen check out my answer it will work for all cases ;)

Comment: I must strongly agree with @ReutSharabani: You need to provide a complete specification of what you want to achieve or at least so many examples of input and output that we can figure out what you want.  Otherwise we will only make educated guesses.  And because of that I fear I have to downvote your question :-/  (And hope you can remedy it so I can remove my vote.)

Comment: @Alfe ReutSharabani Thank you for the comments. Everyone, sorry for some bad description, way to tired, probably. I have updated it and hope it is better now)))

Comment: Does any of the given answers pose valid solution?  If not, please comment with giving an input example which results in a wrong output and explain which output you would have expected instead.

Comment: @Alfe, please refresh the page)

Comment: Did.  Thanx ;-)  Solution derived directly from phrasing the task correctly.  Real masters know how to bring others to phrase their problems so clearly that putting them in code is a cinch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are trying to get rid of all those lists which contain only elements which are also in another list?

```
def eachMasterList(allLists):
  allSets = [ set(lst) for lst in allLists ]
  for lst, s in zip(allLists, allSets):
    if not any(s is not otherSet and s < otherSet for otherSet in allSets):
      yield lst
```

To use the function, try this:

```
print(list(eachMasterList([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7,8], [9, 10, 11, 12], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]])))
```

Comment: This solution is amazing! For `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 6, 5], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12], [11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [111, 222, 333], [444, 555], [777, 888], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888], [1000, 2000, 3000]]` it gives this output: `[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15], [111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 777, 888], [1000, 2000, 3000]]` you truly are a master! A bit ashamed of my poor attempts, but now can see where to go.

Answer (score 1):

You have a big list of lists, and you want to look up a lot of lists in it? Do it like you would handle looking up any other kind of object in a big collection: Store them (or a suitable version, to be exact) in a set to allow fast lookup.

Lists cannot be set elements, but you can transform the small lists to tuples and store those:

```
myindex = set(tuple(sm) for sm in big_list)
```

Then to check if `[1, 3, 4]` is in your `big_list`, you just say:

```
if tuple([1, 3, 4]) in myindex:
    ...
```

If you want to match lists regardless of order (so that `[1, 3, 4]` is considered equal to `[3, 1, 4]`), turn them into sets too. But not regular sets (they can't be set elements either), but `frozenset`:

```
myindex = myindex = set(frozenset(sm) for sm in big_list)
```

That's about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursion function :

```
>>> l =[(1, 3, 2), (4, 5, 6), (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10, 11, 12), (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)]

>>> def find_max_sub(l):
...    for i,j in enumerate(l):
...       for t,k in enumerate(l[i+1:],1):
...             if set(j).intersection(k):
...                 return find_max_sub([set(l.pop(i))|set(l.pop(t))]+l)
...    return l
... 
>>> find_max_sub(l)
[(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12)]
```

All you need is looping over your main list and compare the elements in list with other and when you find to sub lists that have any intersection you pop those elements and add new sub list to main list then call the function with new list.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
def get_subset_list():
    for arr in arrays:
        others = [x for x in arrays if x != arr]
        for other in others:
            for val in arr:
                if val not in other:
                    break
            else:
                break
        else:
            yield arr

import json
x = get_subset_list()
print set([json.dumps(y) for y in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare two arrays by converting them into **strings** then comparing by `__contains__`

```
print (''.join(arr1).__contains__(''.join(arr2)))
```